# How to write the output of ipython command in python text file?

Tags: ipython

I want to capture the output of the following ipython command into a file:
commands and outputs areas follows:

```
`decoder.get_hyp()`

WARNING: "ngram_search.c", line 1000: </s> not found in last frame, using ++NOISE++ instead
INFO: ngram_search.c(1046): lattice start node <s>.0 end node ++NOISE++.171
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1225): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(++NOISE++:171:185) = -2003082
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1263): Joint P(O,S) = -2036704 P(S|O) = -33622
Out[7]: ('WELCOME TO MY TALK', '000000000', -36704586)
```

I want to capture only the part "wellcome to my talk" into my file.

Answer (score 48):

Use the IPython magic function [`store`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html)

```
%store foo >a.txt # Store (overwrite) value of foo to file a.txt

%store foo >>a.txt # Append value of foo to file a.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to read it back to a variable in a similar way?  Say, I stored a list to a .txt, and I want to read the .txt back to a variable. Thank you.

Comment: you can try with %load. Although the best practice is to store the file with pickle.

Comment: Beware that with `%store`, data type like `str` are saved as (<class 'str'>,), and when `%load` it raises an error... Definitely, go with pickle!

Comment: beware you have to type it like this: %store foo >a.txt to work. If you type it in this way: %store foo >  a.txt  you will get a FileNotFound error.

Answer (score 30):

Just do as follow:

```
%save file_name.py _oh[7]
```

PS: Some additional useful command:

```
%save file_name.py _
```

'_' refers to  the previous output.

Or you can:

```
%save file_name.py _oh[i]
```

'i' refers to the output history number, you can see output first via:

```
_oh
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`%%capture` cell magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture) saves the stdout/stderr output of running a command, if that's what you need. Here's the usage syntax:

```
%%capture [--no-stderr] [--no-stdout] [--no-display] [output]
```

And, here's a usage example:

```
In [1]: %%capture my_print_output
    ...: print('test')
    ...:

In [2]: my_print_output
Out[2]: <IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO at 0x7f2efa2c12d0>

In [3]: test_output.show()
test
```

The output object is an instance of [`IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.capture.html#IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO), which has a neat interface for accessing stdout/stderr or combined output.

Comment: Yep. You should use `x=my_print_output.stdout` `%store x > file`

Answer (score 1):

IPython captures the value (output) of the last command in the variable _ (underscore).

```
%edit some_variable
```

will open the value of a variable in your editor.

So, "%edit _", should enable you to edit and save the value of the last command.

See [the History section of the IPython docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.1/interactive/tutorial.html#history)

And to learn about the possible arguments to the %edit magic function, type the following at the ipython prompt:

```
%edit?
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try this on a numpy array I get `'NoneType' object is not iterable`